# Leap Motion: How to make swipe only trigger function once per swipe?

Tags: javascript, audio-player, leap-motion

I am building a leap motion controlled music player, the menu system is controlled with leap motion.

Tilt up and down scrolls through menu items, right swipe selects that item, left swipe goes back up a menu level.

The issue I am having is when you swipe right on 'artist list' menu, it then changes to 'songs' menu and because the leap motion swipe gesture works on frames it triggers my function multiple times so the first song is immediately selected.

Here is relevant code:

```
var updateSelection = function() {
  if(Math.floor(x) == x && $.isNumeric(x)){
    var listLength = $(menu + ' li').size();
    if (x > listLength) x = listLength;
    if (x < 1) x = 1;
    $(menu + ' li').removeClass('active');
    $(menu + ' #' + x + artist ).addClass('active');
     scrollToIt = x + artist;
     idTagX = x;
     if (scrollDirection == "down") {
      var topPos = document.getElementById(scrollToIt).offsetTop;
      document.getElementById('cssmenu').scrollTop = topPos;
      //document.getElementById(scrollToIt).scrollIntoView();
    }
    else if (scrollDirection == "up"){
      var topPos = document.getElementById(scrollToIt).offsetTop;
      document.getElementById('cssmenu').scrollTop = topPos;
      //document.getElementById(scrollToIt).scrollIntoView(true);
    }
  }
}
if(frame.hands.length > 0)
{
  var hand = frame.hands[0];

  pitchRadians = hand.pitch();

  if (pitchRadians > 0.45) {
   newX = x - 0.1;
   x = roundNumber(newX, 2);
   scrollDirection = "up";
   updateSelection();
 }
 else if (pitchRadians < -0.45){
  newX = x + 0.1;
  x = roundNumber(newX, 2);
  scrollDirection = "down";
  updateSelection();
}
else {
  x = parseInt(x);
  updateSelection();
}

}
//--------------------------------------------------Swipe Selection
if (frame.gestures.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < frame.gestures.length; i++) {
    var gesture = frame.gestures[i];

    //---- Swipe ----
    if (gesture.type == "swipe") {
      var isHorizontal = Math.abs(gesture.direction[0]) > Math.abs(gesture.direction[1]);
      if(isHorizontal){
        if(gesture.direction[0] > 0){

          $(menu + ' #' + idTagX + artist).click();

          console.log(artist);
        } else {
          console.log("Menu Left");
         // $("#" + artist).hide();
          //menu = ".artists"
        }
      } else {
        // Vertical swipe              
      }
    }
  }
}


})
```

This might well be a simple fix, I have just been looking at this code too long to get my head round it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a solution to this, detailed below, answering so other users can see for future reference.

```
var prevSwipe = "";
var d = new Date();
var now = d.getTime();
var prevSwipeTime = now;


function rightSwipe () {
          d = new Date();
         if(prevSwipe == "right") {
                    if(prevSwipeTime + 1000 < d.getTime()) { //time elapsed, run code
                              $(menu + ' #' + idTagX + artist).click();
                              prevSwipe = "right";
                              prevSwipeTime = d.getTime();
                              console.log("prev == right");
                    } // otherwise do nothing
          } else {
                   $(menu + ' #' + idTagX + artist).click();
                    prevSwipe = "right";
                    prevSwipeTime = d.getTime();
                    console.log(prevSwipeTime);
                    console.log("prev != right");
          }
}
```

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Thank you very much, I was attempting the same thing in C# and your logic gave me the answer. Very much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad it was of some use!